# One parent with 2 child processes

Tags: c, fork, parent-child

I am trying to create a single parent process with 2 childs. When I run my code i get 3 different child process ID.

```
      int main ()
{
pid_t child_pid, child_pid1;

printf("the main program process ID is %d\n", (int) getpid());

child_pid = fork ();
if (child_pid != 0)
{
    printf(" the parent process ID is %d\n", (int) getppid());
    printf(" the child's process ID is %d\n", (int) child_pid);
}

child_pid1 = fork ();
if (child_pid1 != 0)
{
    printf(" the child's process ID is %d\n", (int) child_pid1);
}

return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Everybody is forking like mad!

Comment: How do you know that you have 3 childs?

Comment: @MadPhysicist; Because parent knows well :)

Comment: I'd say we should stick a fork in this question to see if its done!! : )

Answer (score 2):

The line:

```
child_pid1 = fork ();
```

is being executed by both the original process and the first child process. So you end up with one parent, which creates two child processes, the first of which also creates a child process.

Try it like this:

```
int main ()
{
pid_t child_pid, child_pid1;

printf("the main program process ID is %d\n", (int) getpid());

child_pid = fork ();
if (child_pid != 0)
{
    printf(" the parent process ID is %d\n", (int) getppid());
    printf(" the child's process ID is %d\n", (int) child_pid);
    child_pid1 = fork ();
    if (child_pid1 != 0)
    {
        printf(" the child's process ID is %d\n", (int) child_pid1);
    }
}


return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I run your program I get something like the following (*The part before the dash has been added for explanation purposes*):

```
1 (MAIN) - the main program process ID is 30583
2 (PARENT OF MAIN) - the parent process ID is 15915
3 (FIRST FORK) - the child's process ID is 30584
4 (FORK OF MAIN) - the child's process ID is 30585
1 - the main program process ID is 30583
2 - the parent process ID is 15915
3 - the child's process ID is 30584
1 - the main program process ID is 30583
5 (FORK OF FIRST FORK) - the child's process ID is 30586
1 - the main program process ID is 30583
```

What you are looking at then is actually **5 processes**.

Of course, the process marked "1" is the main process but THREE come from the forks! Basically, the first fork creates two processes from the main process. The second fork is called twice (because of each of the processes are now running through that spot) so it creates TWO more processes. Now, the process marked "2" is actually the parent process for the main process which is why you have FIVE distinct processes id's in your output.

*Edit* - I marked the "names" of the forks so you could see where each of them come from. Hope that helps!